# Model association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a Model in a ruby on rails app `rails g model subject_structure name:string abbreviation:string`

I created the relations

```
class SubjectStructure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects
end

class Subject< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject_structure
end
```

When i run the app i get the error `undefined method subject_structure for #<Subject:0x9d3aa78>`

Im creating an app for an existing database that already has the tables with data in it.

Comment: Add a space between `belongs_to` and `:subject_structure`. Also you didn;t create foreign_key columns, so your associations won't work.

Comment: I did that, but something else seems to be the problem. I don't think i have to run `rake db:migrate` because i already have the table in the database

Comment: How this table got there without running the migration?

Comment: @juan did you add a foreign_key (subject_structure_id) to `Subject`?

Comment: I'm running Ruby 2.2.3 and do not get any errors from omitting spaces between the class name and the inheritance sign `Subject<` or before the symbol argument here `belongs_to:subject_structure`. ActiveRecord associations can be defined without having the foreign key available, so that won't cause an error (however the association will not work). @juan perhaps there is some other relevant code? Try looking at the log file to see exactly where the error occurred (and perhaps share that here)

Comment: its an existing database that already has that table

Comment: yes, `Subject` has a `subject_structure_id` column defined

Comment: @juan please add the schema of the models (it's in `db/schema.rb`)

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after the belongs_to.

Should be

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject_structure
end
```

Comment: I would try running the console with rails c.  Try `SubjectStructure.subjects` and see if that returns anything, then also try the `Subject.subject_structure`.  You can also run `rake db:migrate:status` to make sure your migrations are active.

Answer (score 0):

There's a space missing on the `belongs_to`:

```
class Subject< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject_structure
end
```

Also, `Subject` must have a foreign_key for `SubjectStructure`. Run this migration to create it:

```
rails g migration AddSubjectStructureIdToSubject subject_structure_id:integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space like:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :subject_structure
end
```